# use of undeclared identifier __glibcxx_assert

Tags: c++11, android-ndk

I have some C++11 code that I need to compile with the Android NDK. I'm on Mac OS 10.3.

It makes use of the __glibcxx_assert macro without importing the defining header file. It is not imported previously either.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

#include <mutex>

#include "Fifo.h"

    void Fifo::setReader(int readerIx, Port* p){
        __glibcxx_assert(readerIx >= nReaders_)
        readers_[readerIx].port = p;
    }
```

This should not compile anywhere, am I right? Or Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why are you using that glibc-internal instead of `assert` from `<cassert>`? Presumably `__glibcxx_assert` is included through some of your other `#include`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NDK no longer supports GNU libstdc++, so that's not available. Just use `assert` from `assert.h`.